# I can't solve fluttertoast error in android studio version: fluttertoast: ^8.1.2 >flutter --version Flutter 3.3.10 plz help me

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-8.1.3/lib/fluttertoast.dart:165:28: Error: Member not found: 'Overlay.maybeOf'.
var _overlay = Overlay.maybeOf(context!);
^^^^^^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFZTA.png)

I changed fluttertoast version but I got the same error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your pubspec.lock File & Make sure you have same version in both pubspec.lock & pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Flutter toast v8.1.3 cannot work with a Flutter version older than 3.7.0 because of a [breaking change](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/supplemental-maybeOf-migration) in Flutter v3.7.0. You have to either use fluttertoast v8.1.2 or you have to upgrade your flutter version to v3.7.0+.